# Enable/Disable Ribbon Control On Selection Change Of Mail Item

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

I am developing outlook add-in in C#.

In **Project1**, I am having class which adds controls like below :

```
 internal class ExplorerRibbonUi : MainRibbonUi
    {
        public ExplorerRibbonUi(Func<string, string> manifestLoader) :
            base(RibbonIds.Explorer, manifestLoader)
        {
            Controls.Add(new Controls1());
            Controls.Add(new Controls2());
        }
    }
```

I have added Control2 in Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer.xml file.

In **Project2**, I have a selection change event of mail item. Which is like below :

```
if (objSelectionList != null && objSelectionList.Count == 1 && objSelectionList[1] != null)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem objMailItem = objSelectionList[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (objMailItem != null)
                    {
                        if (BrandingsManager.IsBrandingLoaded()
                            && (Api.Instance.LicenseManager.IsLicensed()
                            && (this.IsMailItemBodySecured(objMailItem) || this.IsMailItemSetForDecryption(objMailItem))
                            && this.IsRecipientSupportEncryption(objMailItem)))
                        {
                            //ENABLE RIBBON CONTROL
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //DISABLE RIBBON CONTROL
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I want to enable/disable control of ribbon based on above condition. Note that, This is not VSTO add-in. I am not able to get ribbon controls in Project2 from Project1.

Comment: Are these projects different add-ins or just dependent assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the controls from the add-in where they were created only. And you can't access controls created by other add-ins until you have a public methods provided by the add-in developers. Consider using standard .net mechanisms such as `Remoting` for calling the code from another application. Also you may consider implementing a common interface in the add-in which can be consumed by others, see [Call code in VSTO Add-ins from other Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

I'd recommend using ribbon callbacks instead. Note, you can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures in COM add-ins. For each of the callbacks that the add-in implements, the responses are cached.

For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getEnabled` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the state loads, and then if the state needs to be updated, the cached state is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

In the ribbon XML markup you need to specify the following callback to get an instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface which allows calling the `Invalidate` or InvalidateControl methods:

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>
```

The callback accepts an instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface which should be cached for further usage when required to updated the state of controls.

The `getEnabled` callback should have the following signature:

```
C#: bool GetEnabled(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)

C++: HRESULT GetEnabled([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfEnabled)

Visual Basic: Function GetEnabled(control as IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon controls can only be accessed/modified by the addin that added them. You need to either include the logic that enables/disabled the buttons in your addin, or expose some kind of API in your addin that your second project can call into - you can you can do that by overriding `RequestComAddInAutomationService` method on your `ThisAddin` class (the returned object must be marked as `[ComVisible(true)]` and `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`). Your second project can then use `Application.COMAddins` collection to retrieve your addin (project 1) `COMAddin` object (you can use `COMAddin.ProgId` property to identify it) and use `COMAddin.Object` property to call the object returned by the `RequestComAddInAutomationService` method.